# Packaging Perl Mojolicious web application

Tags: linux, perl, packaging, mojolicious

I've written a small web application in Perl and I want to package it up so others can use it. My application has the following components

- Various Perl modules from CPAN
- My own modules
- A MySQLdatabase
- Apache2 configuration

I'm not really sure where to start. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Submitting a module to CPAN is easy once you get the hang of it, but at first it takes a while  to learn. There are several guides to help you, but choose one that was written within the last few years. Here is one: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=879515

You will need to learn at least a little bit about one of the build tools. I like [Module::Build](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aBuild), some others like ExtUtils::MakeMaker (I don't personally) or the pseudo-tool [Dist::Zilla](http://dzil.org) which may be used to ease the process of using the previous.

I might suggest trying to releasing a tiny toy module under the `Acme::` namespace to try things before uploading your real module.

Look at some of the dists written by your favorite authors to see what they do. For example mine are [here](https://metacpan.org/author/JBERGER) or [here](https://github.com/jberger) including my Mojolicious app [Galileo](https://github.com/jberger/Galileo).

Finally, as documented [here](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Making_your_application_installable), to make a Mojolicious app installable you need to move your static files into an installable location. I have made a plugin which can help (if you follow its recipe) called [Mojolicious::Plugin::InstallablePaths](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aInstallablePaths).

Good luck!

P.S. if you comment with a link to a github repo I would be happy to make some comments (but you will still have to do the heavy lifting of course :-) )

Comment: Hi Joel, Thank you very much for your detailed and very helpful response. I'm very new to coding in perl, so my code is rather embarrassing in comparison to your efforts :). But you have provided me with a wealth of information so that between my fulltime job and other studies I will hopefully be able to improve and deploy my little webapp. cheers!